# Unable to access the url of access token using git push

Tags: github

I generate a new token after the previous one expired and while trying to git push changes into my GitHub, a message "unable to access token url keeps popping up".
What to do to rectify this??

Comment: Are you using MacOS? If so, you might have to update your credentials from the MacOS keychain as [so](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/updating-credentials-from-the-macos-keychain)

Comment: No am using normal computer